# Android - Error in try to access methods inside OkHttp 4.x

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I'm getting this errors when i try to do this fun ->

```
private fun getUrl(response: Response\<\*\>): String {
val networkResponse = response.raw().networkResponse()
return networkResponse?.request()?.url()?.toString() ?: response.raw().request().url()
.toString()
}
```

errors ->

```
Using 'networkResponse(): Response?' is an error. moved to val
Using 'request(): Request' is an error. moved to val
Using 'url(): HttpUrl' is an error. moved to val
Using 'request(): Request' is an error. moved to val
Using 'url(): HttpUrl' is an error. moved to val
```

Can anyone help me? pls

I tried somethings that i found on Internet but nothing is helping

Answer (score 0):

> Using 'networkResponse(): Response?' is an error. moved to val
>
> Using 'request(): Request' is an error. moved to val
>
> Using 'url(): HttpUrl' is an error. moved to val
>
> Using 'request(): Request' is an error. moved to val
>
> Using 'url(): HttpUrl' is an error. moved to val

Means you shouldn't call them as functions, instead access as property/field. Example, instead of `request()`, use `request` without paranthesis.

You also seem to be mixing imports, `Response` exists both in okhttp & Retrofit libraries, make sure you import the correct one. I am guessing this is what you want:

```kotlin
private fun getUrl(response: retrofit2.Response<String>): String {
    val networkResponse:okhttp3.Response? = response.raw().networkResponse()
    return networkResponse?.request?.url?.toString() ?: response.raw().request().url().toString()
}
```

Comment: when i try to access as property/field(the way that u show), they dont show them to access, only show the fun of them with paranthesis

Comment: Which okhttp version are you using exactly?

Comment: I am using okhttp3:4.10.0

Comment: @4544545 you are mixing imports, Response class exists in both okhttp3 & retrofit2

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit dumb, but you have to cast `response.raw()` to `okhttp3.Response`:

```
val networkResponse = (response.raw() as okhttp3.Response).networkResponse
```

You should then get the IDE error with the auto-fix suggestion of using the val value for those method references.